# How to resample DAILY data to MONTHLY and then resample MONTHLY to ANNUAL when working with multi-indexed columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation, pandas-resample

So I'm analysing my budget based on daily expenses that I aggregate monthly "**DFM**" (OK), but then I want to aggregate **DFM** on a yearly basis (**DFM_Y**) to obtain "*monthly_min*", "*monthly_max*" and "*monthly_mean*", but I can't find the right way to handle the multi-indexed columns in the **agg( )** context.

My current code with **DFY** gives the "*sum*" alright, but the rest is all daily ("*daily_min*", "*daily_max*" and "*daily_mean*", which is not super informative)

Any suggestions on how to create **DFM_Y** ?

[Here's an example of DFM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmHjl.png)

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='12/31/2023', freq='D'),
                   'code' : [1,2,3,4,5] * 73,
                   'value': range(365)})

# Set index 'date' for "resample" 
# --> Resample by MONTH, YEAR and YEAR based on MONTLY VALUES
df = df.set_index('date')

# Le GROUPBY de SOMMES par MOIS sert pour le GROUPBY par ANNÉE pcq on veut
# les MIN, MAX, MOY et SUM par mois et non par transactions
dfm = df.groupby('code').resample("M").agg({
    'value': ['sum', 'min', 'mean', 'max'], 
}).round()

dfy = df.groupby('code').resample("Y").agg({
    'value': ['sum', 'min', 'mean', 'max']
}).round()


dfm_y = ??????????????????????????????????
```

Comment: Please make a [mre], meaning show your desired output and provide some example data. Pictures are OK for illustration, but to try things for ourselves, [we need text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). It'd also help to translate the comments into English since not everyone speaks French here. Lastly, it'd help to show us what you've tried, even if you don't think it's very close, cause you might be closer than you think :)

Comment: With this (fake) dataset, what are your expected values (in other words, compute them by hand and include them in the question)